# How to reset dynamic mock in each test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm mocking a json I import in every test like that:

```
jest.mock('../assets/items.json', () => items);
```

so it looks like this:

```
it('test A',()=>{
    const itemsA=[1,2,3]
    jest.mock('../assets/items.json', () => itemsA);
    const expectedItems = selectQuery('...items')
    expect(expectedItems).toBe(itemsA)
}



 it('test A',()=>{
        const itemsB=[3,4,5]
        jest.mock('../assets/items.json', () => itemsB);
         const expectedItems = selectQuery('...items')
        expect(expectedItems).toBe(itemsB)
 }
```

the problem is when I do that, the jest.mock() is mocking only the itemsA and ignores the mock on itemsB, I tried doing this :

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  
  })
```

in the file itself I use something like this:

```
 const items = await import('../assets/items.json');
```

but it didn't help, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`jest.doMock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options). Specifically,

> When using babel-jest, calls to mock will automatically be hoisted to the top of the code block. Use this method if you want to explicitly avoid this behavior.

> One example when this is useful is when you want to mock a module differently within the same file:

I would change your `jest.mock` calls to `jest.doMock`. Also include a call to `jest.resetModules()` before each test:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules()
})
```